How many ways 4 identical apples and 4 identical oranges be distributed among 6 children if each child gets at least 1 fruit?
My first approach to solving this problem was :
Let us say 4 apples and 2 oranges are given to the kids initially this can be done ${6}\choose{4}$ ways , then remaining two oranges are identical and are to be distributed among 6 kids
It's analogous to the case when
a+b+c+d+e+f= 2
Where a, b  and so on are assigned to an individual kid and this can be solved for by using stars and bars method ${7}\choose{5}$
Then , same is for 2 apples and 4 oranges
This adds upto $2×{{6}\choose{4}}×{6\choose4}$
Now , say 3 apples and 3 oranges are distributed  ways , then the remaining of each is to be given to the 6 kids similar to the way the above were and that gives us ${6\choose5}×{6\choose3}$
Adding the above , we get 750
Another method I used to solve this question was
Taking the following cases
One child gets 3 fruits while the others get one each.
This can be done by giving the kid one apple and two oranges
Two apples and one orange,
Three oranges,
Three apples,
These can be arranged using simple permutation. The total cases are:
$2×2!{6\choose4}+ 2×3!{6\choose3}$
Secondly two kids get two fruits.
And this can be done 540 ways , this adds upto 720.
The first method and second method result in different answers , why so?

I'm so sorry , its meant to be 6...I copied it from a text book so it must've made an error

It's no good handing out one fruit to each kid and then handing out the extras...there's no way to tell which piece of fruit was in the original batch and which was extra, so you inevitably overcount.  thus your first method fails.

Yes you're right, I couldn't figure out which cases were being repeated  and causing the over-count

The multiply counted cases arise from the kids who get more than one piece, and the extent of the overcounting depends on the pattern involved.  Usually, there is no easy fix for this sort of over counting.  Nothing conceptually wrong with the second method...I didn't check the details so I can't speak to the arithmetic, but the method ought to work.

It seems like this is most naturally an inclusion-exclusion problem.

I second the motion for Inclusion Exclusion.

@ThomasAndrews , yes it does seem that way but making cases seemed to be a shorter approach for me.

If you wan to do cases, the best way is to seperate into two cases, one where a single child gets three and the other where two children each gets two. But then the cases will require sub cases.

I agree with PIE, though expressed in its complementary form, @ThomasAndrews. Namely, $|\cap \bar{A_i} | = |S - \cup A_i|$ where $A_i$ is the event that child $i$ gets no fruit.

In particular, getting the class right can be tricky, and will be hard to generalize to different numbers of children and fruits.

Do we assume that the children are also indistinguishable? It makes a big difference. Your attempts seem to assume that they are, but that wasn't obvious from the problem statement.

The answers for small numbers of fruit can be computed reasonably easily by first considering the ways the fruit can be put into groups:-
AAAAO(OOO), AAAOO(OOA), AAOOO(OAA), AOOOO(AAA),
AAAA(OO)(OO), AAAO(OO)(AO), AAOO(AO)(AO), AAOO(AA)(OO), AOOO(AA)(AO), OOOO(AA)(AA).
For each of these 10 ways we then allocate the 6 'objects' to people noting any multiplicities:-
$$6!(\frac{1}{4!}+\frac{1}{3!2!}+\frac{1}{2!3!}+\frac{1}{4!}+\frac{1}{4!2!}+\frac{1}{3!}+\frac{1}{2!2!2!}+\frac{1}{2!2!}+\frac{1}{3!}+\frac{1}{4!2!})=720$$

Nice ! (+1) Can you tell what system you have adopted in the groupings so that you don't miss any ? It is not very evident to me.

@true blue anil. I organised it initially according to the possibilities for the 'singletons' i.e. AAAAO, AAAOO,AAOOO,AOOOO, AAAA, AAAO, etc

Thanks, I didn't discern the pttern because I was looking at the whole strings !

Let $A$ be the set of all ways to distribute the fruit to the 8 students, with no restrictions.
Let $A_i$ be the set of distributions in which child $i$ gets no fruit.
Then you want to count $|A\setminus (A_1\cup\cdots\cup A_6)|,$ which makes this a perfect problem for inclusion-exclusion. I think we get:
$$\sum_{k=0}^6(-1)^k\binom6k\binom{9-k}4^2$$
A pain to compute, admittedly, but you don't need to argue cases, and generalizes more easily.

the question says $6$ children not $8$

Whoops, fixed. @NotaSalmonFish
